# Input file (Hello_World) is neither a Mach-O file nor a fat archive: Class-dump

Tags: ios

I am trying to use class-dump in iPhone 14.3. However, there is an error. Can you advise?

```
ANT-iPhone:/var/containers/Bundle/Application/61669A90-8CF9-4991-943F-5E9F097A3A5B/Hello_World.app root# otool -Vh Hello_World

Hello_World:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags

MH_MAGIC_64   ARM64        ALL  0x00     EXECUTE    24       2840   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE

ANT-iPhone:/var/containers/Bundle/Application/61669A90-8CF9-4991-943F-5E9F097A3A5B/Hello_World.app root# class-dump Hello_World

2023-03-05 19:46:00.418 class-dump[8334:2699202] === SSL Kill Switch 2: Preference set to 1.
2023-03-05 19:46:00.425 class-dump[8334:2699202] We don't support 64-bit Mach-O files.

class-dump: Input file (Hello_World) is neither a Mach-O file nor a fat archive.
```

Comment: `We don't support 64-bit Mach-O files` indicates that the `class-dump` tool is outdated as all iOS software is now 64 bit. I would download the whole .app directory and open the binary in Ghidra.

Comment: Can class-dump software swift programming language by the way?

Comment: The first 64bit iPhone was introduced 2013, Swift was introduced 2014 (and became binary stable AFAIR ~2019). If class-dump does not support 64bit how likely it is it supports Swift which was introduced later?